# How to scroll to top of my single pages with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm using the following code in an `onAppend` function to scroll to the top of any page.

The scroll should fire after a play button is clicked and a YouTube vid is starting to load - the function has a `onAppend` event which works fine...

So I just need the scroll function. Now I tried to implement this code just to all of my single WordPress posts.

**EDIT:** The solution on [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/9036446) does not work in this case. So the "possible duplicate" request should be ignored.

```
var body = jQuery("html, body");
    body.stop().animate({scrollTop:0}, 500, function() { 
    // alert("Finished animating");
});
```

The HTML of the single posts looks like

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" lang="en-US">
    <head>...</head>
    <body class="post-template-default single single-post postid-880">
        <nav id="menu" class="xs-menu">....</nav>
        <div id="single-post-wrapper" class="single-post-class">
        ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea how to scroll ONLY to the top of the single posts in WordPress - for example to the `#single-post-wrapper` or to the top top of the entire post?

Comment: On what do you wanna fire a scroll? Could you show structure how multiple posts look in HTML? Do they have a wrapper? Do they have unique id's?
 Do you fire a scroll from within them or from somewhere else completely? IMHO those are essentials for a clean answer here, as of now it's guessing. By top of page you mean to the top of entire page or just some post?

Comment: @DanteTheSmith - i will update my question...

Comment: add some condition around your animate, to check if your are on a single post

Comment: @DanteTheSmith - i updated the question. Yes there is a wrap with an id. It should be enough to scroll to #single-post-wrapper. The scroll should fire after a play button is clicked and a youtube vid is starting to load - the function has a onAppend event wich works fine... so i just need the scroll function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: @mr.void - i put the code into a custom.js file. I have no idea how to put a condition to the function like "if is single" in Wordpress or so.... i only try to scroll to the #single-post-wrapper...

Comment: @MoshFeu - your mentioned answer dont work in my case

Comment: It's the exact answer you just accepted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code...where id is the wrap

```
            var id = "get your id here";
            jQuery("html, body").animate({
               scrollTop : jQuery(id).offset().top
            }, 1800);
```

Thanks !

Comment: Works - thx. Maybe you add a # in front of the get your id here. best

Comment: I used the following to scroll a little bit further `scrollTop : jQuery(id).offset().top + (-100)`

Comment: that may be because of padding/margin to the target id i guess.

Answer (score 1):

you can scroll to an element by passing it's top windows offset as `$(selector).offset().top`

See this working snippet

```js
$(".stop").on("click",function(e){
  $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
});


$(".spost").on("click",function(e){
  $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop:$("#single-post-wrapper").offset().top
    }, 'slow');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
<button class="stop">scroll to top</button>
    <button class="spost">scroll to single-post-wrapper</button>
    
    <div class="post-template-default single single-post postid-880">
        <nav id="menu" class="xs-menu">menu</nav>
        <br><br><br><br><br>
        <div id="single-post-wrapper" class="single-post-class">
      single-post-wrapper<button class="stop">scroll to top</button>  <br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <button class="stop">scroll to top</button>
    <button class="spost">scroll to single-post-wrapper</button>
    
</div>
```

Comment: thx - works to. But the answer from @aravind was perfect. best